# Key error in Django Rest Framework when using serializers.ChoiceField with tuples

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django 1.7.7 and Django Rest Framework 3.1.1.

When I serialize this model

```
class Question(models.Model):
  QUESTION_TYPES = (
    (10,'Blurb'),
    (20,'Group Header'),
    (21,'Group Footer'),
    (30,'Sub-Group Header'),
    (31,'Sub-Group Footer'),
    (50,'Save Button'),
    (100,'Standard Question'),
    (105,'Text-Area Question'),
    (110,'Multiple-Choice Question'),
    (120,'Standard Sub-Question'),
    (130,'Multiple-Choice Sub-Question')
)
type = models.IntegerField(default=100,choices=QUESTION_TYPES)
```

using this viewset/serializer:

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   type = serializers.ChoiceField(choices='QUESTION_TYPES')

   class Meta:
      model = Question    

class QuestionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   model = Question
   serializer_class = QuestionSerializer

   def get_queryset(self):
      return Question.objects.all()
```

I get a KeyError '10' (or whatever QUESTION_TYPES key is the first to be serialized from the Questions table).

The error seems to be thrown by rest_framework/fields.py in to_representation
        return self.choice_strings_to_values[six.text_type(value)]

Is there anything obvious I am doing wrong? Is there a problem using tuples with serializer.ChoiceField?

John

Comment: What about: `ChoiceField(choices=Question.QUESTION_TYPES)`?

Comment: That has the desirable effect of not throwing an error, but it still displays the key rather than the text such as "blurb". I have also tried `type = serializers.CharField(source='get_type_display')`, and while that displays the text correctly, rather than the key, it appears to be read only. I cannot for the life of me write to it, even if I try to write the key.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like `ChoiceField` has some problems when trying to override the behavior in the serializer itself.

You can go around this though by using two separate fields:

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=Question.QUESTION_TYPES)
    type_display = serializers.CharField(source='get_type_display',
                                         read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
```

Answer (score 2):

It all comes down to this [line](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/3.1.1/rest_framework/fields.py#L1022) in the ChoiceField class. It uses the key twice.

```
self.choice_strings_to_values = dict([
    (six.text_type(key), key) for key in self.choices.keys()
])
```

You can change this behavior by creating your own field serializer extending the ChoiceField class

```
class DisplayChoiceFieldSerializers(serializers.ChoiceField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DisplayChoiceFieldSerializers, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.choice_strings_to_values = dict([
            (six.text_type(key), unicode(value)) for key, value in self.choices.iteritems()
        ])
```

Comment: Your class works great and just like I thought the ChoiceField would work. Do you know if a bug has been reported on this? It seems like such an obvious bug it feels like I'm missing something. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, after using this class for a while, we reverted to the regular implementation, because it made it easier on our javascript end. So I don't think it is a bug, just a different use case.

Comment: Thanks, this solution works for me. This is the code for Python 3 http://stackoverflow.com/a/35575125/727716

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent on Python 3

```
self.choice_strings_to_values = dict([
    (six.text_type(key), str(value)) for key, value in self.choices.items()
])
```